# Local and global scope

Tags: javascript, hoisting

```js
var a = 1

function b() {
  a = 20
  return

  function a() {}
}
b()
console.log(a)
```

I thought the output would be 20 but its 1 ? The execution context of function b would access variable a from the GEC and update its value imo. Why is it so?

Comment: Why would it be `10`? Did you mean `20`?

Comment: The inner `function a() {}` makes `a` a local variable. So it doesn't assign to the global variable.

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before posting for questions that may already exist that address your question. This has been asked and answered many times here.

Answer (score 1):

[function declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) declare a variable sharing the name of the function in the current scope (like `var` does) and are [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).

`function a` therefore creates a local variable `a` inside `function b` and is that *that* variable that you overwrite.

---

Some people prefer to use arrow functions with explicit variable declarations. That creates an **error** instead of having the behaviour that surprised you.

```js
var a = 1

function b() {
  a = 20
  return

  const a = () => {}
}
b()
console.log(a)
```

Comment: okay, so if function a wouldn't be present then the o/p would be 20 I imagine?

Comment: @ShivanshRaghav why do you need to imagine?

Comment: @ShivanshRaghav As long as you don't use `function`, `var`, `let`, or `const` to declare `a` in the function. If you just do `a = function() {}` it won't have a local declaration.